# Solving for a fundamental matrix (when is an extra procedure required?)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&3\\3&1\\\end{bmatrix}\qquad $

To find the fundamental matrix of $y' = Ay$ with $y_0 =\begin{bmatrix}2\\4\end{bmatrix}$

I found the eigenvalues of $A$ as $-2,4$

The eigenvectors correspondingly are as $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\\end{bmatrix}$ and
$\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\\end{bmatrix}\ $

Is this sufficient to conclude that the fundamental matrix  $\phi=\begin{bmatrix}-e^{-2t}&e^{4t}\\e^{2t}&e^{4t}\\\end{bmatrix}\\$?

I will appreciate if someone can tell on what if there's more to be done in finding the fundamental matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental matrix is actually

$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} e^{-2t} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{4t} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}.$$

Putting aside the sign error, what you wrote is the product of the first two matrices. The third matrix is needed to change bases to the basis of eigenvectors of $A$.

Things look like this in general except when $A$ is non-diagonalizable, for example this doesn't work as is when $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. There is a generalization for this case, though.

Comment: I wouldn't need to multiply by the third matrix (the inverse) in case of a non-diagonalizable matrix? Can you please tell more about the generalization...

Comment: @Harold For a non-diagonalizable matrix it is similar except that the matrix in the middle is the exponential of a triangular matrix called the Jordan normal form of $A$. The exponential of a triangular matrix will be a triangular matrix again which will have off-diagonal entries that look like $t^n e^{\lambda t}$ for some positive integers $n$. This is fairly easy to look up...